# Finding Arc Length of Polar Curve DIRECTLY

Tags: calculus, curves, polar-coordinates, plane-curves

I want to find the arc length formula for a polar curve directly without having to use the arc length formula for cartesian coordinates. The integrand $\sqrt{r^2+(r')^2}$ is a bit strange to me because it indicated a triangle with bases $r$ and $r'$ and hypotenuse infinitesimally close to $r$. For reference the formula I am thining about is $\int\sqrt{r^2+(r')^2}d\theta$ where $r=r(\theta)$.

The cartesian arc length formula makes more sense to me because all sides of the triangle $ds,dx,dy$ are infinitesimal.

Comment: The origin of the formula in the differential form you describe is $$ds^2  = r^2d\theta^2+dr^2$$ where the sides of the triangle are $dr$ and $rd\theta$

Comment: @NinadMunshi That helps my intuition and gives me a good idea of how to prove the formula.

Comment: See another post based on cosine law [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895896/derive-the-formula-for-the-arc-length-in-polar-coordinates).